# For iOS, how to print the type of a object

Tags: ios

I  try the `isKindOf` method to print the type. But I want to know any other way to print the type of a object? Seeking for help.

Comment: Simple try with NSLog

Comment: Why would you want to use a different way of getting the type?

Comment: Please define what type of an object is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function: `NSStringFromClass()` to do that:

```
NSLog(@"class for object: %@", NSStringFromClass([someObject class]));
```

That will give you a printable string of the type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want to use `isKindOfClass`. To test if object is an instance of class X:

```
[yourObject isMemberOfClass:[X class]]
```

This will return the boolean value which will indicate that the instance is of your class or not.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myObject class]
```

will get you the class object.

You can use isKindOfClass or isMemberOfClass  for check object type

For example:

```
if ([myObject isMemberOfClass:[systemclass class]])
```

for futher detail you can refer https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html

In short `isKindOfClass` means the object inherits from the class, `isMemberOfClass` means exactly the same class

Answer (score -2):

Try this 
     if([yourObject isKindOfClass:[X class]]){
    NSLog(@"Object is X Class Type");
    }